# Json what is proper structure for my class?

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-phone-8

I manged to get my json returned but I am having trouble returning it back into my class says cause its array. But I am using a deserialize method helper i studied from books. And should work.

So the question I need answered is how does my class need to be properly structured to decode the json into the city object.

I am grabbing my json via method which works

```
     /// <summary>
        /// Utility function to get/post WCFRESTService
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="methodRequestType">RequestType:GET/POST</param>
        /// <param name="methodName">WCFREST Method Name To GET/POST</param>
        /// <param name="bodyParam">Parameter of POST Method (Need serialize to JSON before passed in)</param>
        /// <returns>Created by David</returns>
    private async Task<string> WCFRESTServiceCall(string methodRequestType, string methodName, string bodyParam = "")
    {
            string ServiceURI = "/launchwebservice/index.php/webservice/" + methodName;
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(methodRequestType == "GET" ? HttpMethod.Get : HttpMethod.Post, ServiceURI);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyParam))
            {
                request.Content = new StringContent(bodyParam, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            }
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            string jsongString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return jsongString;
     }
```

Then I am using the deserialize method

```
    public static class Helpers
    {    
      public static List<T> Deserialize<T>(this string SerializedJSONString)
        {
            var stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(SerializedJSONString);
            return stuff;
        }
    }
```

I am calling the above in the following manner

```
     string jsonresult = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "cinema_city");    
     var data = jsonresult.Deserialize<Citys>();    
     var dialog = new MessageDialog(jsonresult);
     await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Which when I check `jsonresult` it is indeed returning the json but in square brackets for some reason.

Which gives me the following error:

[image]

My Class of city is as follows

```
    public class City
    {
      public string id { get; set; }
      public string timing_title { get; set; }
   }

   public class Citys
   {
      public List<City> city { get; set; }
   }
```

**Edit To Show The jason data**

> {"city":[{"id":"5521","timing_title":"Lahore"},{"id":"5517","timing_title":"Karachi"},{"id":"5538","timing_title":"Islamabad"},{"id":"5535","timing_title":"Rawalpindi"},{"id":"5518","timing_title":"Hyderabad"},{"id":"5512","timing_title":"Faisalabad"},{"id":"8028","timing_title":"Gujranwala"},{"id":"8027","timing_title":"Gujrat"}]}

**Edit to show error**
Error on dezerilize event ?
[image]

Comment: FYI, ***Cities***.  The json is an array of city objects, so `jsonresult.Deserialize<City[]>()` would work fine.

Comment: @Will tried that didnt work got the same excpetion

Comment: Well, I can tell you that isn't true.  Perhaps you could try it again and paste the (absolutely different) error message in an [edit]?  Also, use the exception dialog--there's a "copy exception details to the clipboard" link on it.  THAT has all the info needed to debug your issue.  An image is worse than useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your classes json going to be:

For City class

```
 {  id: "some string", timing_title:"some string" }
```

and for Citys class:

```
 { city: [ {  id: "some string", timing_title:"some string" }, ... ] }
```

I belive you have a typo in property name - it is city now, but really should be cities.

Another issue I see is that you are mixing together Citys class and List. They are not the same and you cannot serialize/deserialize them to each other.

Correct json for List going to be:

```
[ {  id: "some string", timing_title:"some string" } ,... ]
```

compare it to Citys class above.

**UPDATE**: After reading it again, you are trying to deserialize List to Citys. That is what your exeption says. Probably that is what you wanted to say:

```
public static class Helpers
{    
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this string SerializedJSONString)
    {
        var stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(SerializedJSONString);
        return stuff;
    }
}

string jsonresult = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "cinema_city");    
var data = jsonresult.Deserialize<Citys>();    
var dialog = new MessageDialog(jsonresult);
await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: please see edit above to include data the data above i cannot change the json response this is already running application

Comment: @david Yeap, that is exactly what I am saying, you are receiveing Citys object deserialized, not List<Citys> ( which you are trying to deserialize it to )

Comment: how are you invoking the helper method their was i invoking the wrong one?

Comment: when i try that I am getting the following Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1501 No overload for method 'Deserialize' takes 1 arguments popcornpk C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\81StoreLiveAppsPhoneOnlyLIVE\popcornpk\popcornpkhub\popcornpk\popcornpk\DataModel\popcornpk_Dal.cs 26

Comment: you can call extension method like you did `var data = jsonresult.Deserialize<Citys>();`. It is the same thing.

Comment: its not allowing me to pass the json data now cause of abouve error ?

Comment: I have included the edit I am getting n the above edit

Comment: hope u can help driving me nuts the differences between 8.0 and 8.1 phone bring back add reference

Comment: @david, I updated the code in the answer, but I am not sure what your new issues is.

Comment: i think its my class is the problem if you could define how that should be in the answer thanks

Comment: its ok its now working though i read somewhere that httpclient caches data is that the case if so how do you make sure it always fetches lattest data one thing i dont want though is have to use var how do i make sure that it of list type city so i can reference it in code correctly? Cause what i want to be able to do is return the list in that  for example   var _citys = jsonresult.Deserialize<Citys>();       var dialog = new MessageDialog(jsonresult);
return cityList ?
            await dialog.ShowAsync();

Comment: You better create another question and put this details in it.

Comment: please see other quesiton here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952133/return-list-instead-of-an-item-webservice-phone-8-1-uap